# Standalone spark cluster Authorization with Ranger

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-ranger

I'm working on a setup of EC2 machines that has  standalone Spark cluster, Hive, Apache Ranger. Hive is integrated to Ranger.

As Ranger doesn't have support for Spark-SQL JDBC (port 10015), i tried this open source project https://github.com/yaooqinn/spark-authorizer for Spark Authorization. But didn't work as it seems to rely on yarn resource manager.

I wanted to know any possible ways to acheive authorization on Spark-sql with Apache Ranger.

We are not using any distributions implemented, so features like SPARK-LLAP in hortonworks is not an option.

I have already tried what is explained in http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ranger-user/201601.mbox/%3CCAC1CY9P7iek6U6VDwLEXvLdCNRTcJzk5UWg3sei1MuUMCGrtWA@mail.gmail.com%3E , but that didn't work either.

Have raised a spark jira last year for this but doesnt seem to have picked up yet. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24503

We are using Spark 2.3, Hive 2.3, Ranger 1.0.

Comment: Any luck with this issue?

Comment: I have answered my own question below. See the link for custom code.

Comment: I'm not able to see your answer nor the custom code. Did you post an answer?

Comment: answer was deleted by community, i expanded and reposted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a simple authentication java application to spark-sql port 10015.

```
package hive.test;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.security.sasl.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.hive.service.auth.PasswdAuthenticationProvider;

/*
 javac -cp $HIVE_HOME/lib/hive-service-0.11-mapr.jar SampleAuthenticator.java -d .
 jar cf sampleauth.jar hive
 cp sampleauth.jar $HIVE_HOME/lib/.
*/


public class SampleAuthenticator implements PasswdAuthenticationProvider {

  Hashtable<String, String> store = null;

  public SampleAuthenticator () {
    store = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    store.put("user1", "passwd1");
    store.put("user2", "passwd2");
  }

  @Override
  public void Authenticate(String user, String  password)
      throws AuthenticationException {

    String storedPasswd = store.get(user);

    if (storedPasswd != null && storedPasswd.equals(password))
      return;

    throw new AuthenticationException("SampleAuthenticator: Error validating user");
  }

}
```

Configure the following properties in the hive-site.xml file on each node where HiveServer2 is installed:

`hive.server2.authentication    CUSTOM
hive.server2.custom.authentication.class    The authentication class name.`

```
<property>
<name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
<value>CUSTOM</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.server2.custom.authentication.class</name>
<value>hive.test.SampleAuthenticator</value>
</property>
```

Then restart Hiveserver2 to apply the changes:

reference: https://mapr.com/docs/52/Hive/HiveServer2-CustomAuth.html

Comment: Authentication and authorization are not same things. What you show is basic authentication which does not cover the access control needs.